# What is the equivalent of ipconfig/displaydns (and flushdns) in OS X?

Tags: terminal, macos, dns

I need to find how to display my DNS cache on the mac. I have tried 
multi Google searches but failed to come up with a good solution. 
The best I found was how to remove the cache with the command 
`sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` which is great but I need to see the cache to see if the change works.

Answer (score 5):

As @PrasseethaKR and @kjagiello point out, on High Siera mDNSResponer has moved from `syslog` to `log` function. In addition, your DNS lookups are now considered private and will show as such in both Console and `log stream`.

To view your DNS lookups in real time on High Sierra open an Terminal and run:

```
sudo log config --mode "private_data:on"
log stream --predicate 'process == "mDNSResponder"' --info
```

To go back to using private just run the following command.

```
sudo log config --mode "private_data:off"
```

AFAIK you cannot view the contents of old private messages, only messages logged with `private_data:on` can appear. To view your entire history use the `show` command  Because it can return a large amount of data I also use `--last` to limit the data, e.g. the last 2 hours would be...

```
log show --last 2h --predicate 'process == "mDNSResponder"' --info
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

To see the DNS cache, you can use the following command in Terminal to dump a snapshot summary of the internal state of mDNSResponder to `/var/log/system.log`:

```
sudo killall -INFO mDNSResponder
```

Then to review, you can either use Console and filter using mDNSResponder or since Terminal is already handy just use:

```
grep mDNSResponder /var/log/system.log
```

To flush the DNS cache, use the following command:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Comment: That didn't work for me on High Sierra